# Applying wand to all images in a directory

Tags: python, pdf, wand, magickwand

I try to convert all the pdf of a directory into images, but I have an issues because it only convert one pdf not all of them.

```
import matplotlib
import pytesseract
import os
import argparse
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import PyPDF2
from wand.image import Image as wi

for filename in os.listdir(src_path):
    count = count + 1

    # apply tesseract OCR and write to text file in specified target directory
    target_path = args.trg_dir

    # check if a file is a directory
    if os.path.isdir(filename):
        pass
    else:
        # check if a file is a pdf
        try:
            PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(src_path, filename), "rb"))
        except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:
        else:
            pdf = wi(filename=filename, resolution=300)
            pdfimage = pdf.convert("jpeg")
            i=1
            for img in pdfimage.sequence:
                page = wi(image=img)
                page.save(filename=str(i)+".jpg")
                i +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try:

```
files = [file for file in os.listdir(src_path) if file.endswith(".pdf")]
for file in files:
    with wi(file, resolution=300) as img_pdf:
        for page, img in enumerate(img_pdf.sequence):
            wi(img).save(f"{file}_{page}.jpg")
```